# Two simultaneous equation with enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want the out put in the following form. How to code for this.

1. asddjjd      Two tab space          dnnkdnnd
2. dkjdjdjf     Two tab space          hfdhshdsh
3. dfjdjfdsj    Two tab space          djfdj
4. djfjdf       Two tab space          djjsfjfjd
5. jdjfhhf      Two tab space          dffjdj

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this suit?  Here, the first item plus tab space is specified to take up 3cm in the `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mytabbed[2]{\makebox[3cm][l]{#1}#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\mytabbed{asddjjd}{dnnkdnnd}
\item\mytabbed{dkjdjdjf}{hfdhshdsh}
\item\mytabbed{dfjdjfdsj}{djfdj}
\item\mytabbed{djfjdf}{djjsfjfjd}
\item\mytabbed{jdjfhhf}{dffjdj}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]